# float left every other item echo php

Tags: php, css, list, css-float, echo

im trying to float left every other UL tag, and i know i should flaot left every item and every other item clear:left, from what i've read, but the thing is i dont know how many UL or LI would appear because im echoing from a data base.

this is the CSS:

```
.clientes_provincia li{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;   
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.clientes_comuna li{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
.clientes_giro li{  
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:disc;
}
.clientes_nombre li{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:circle;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

and this is the php code, where i echo the list:

```
<?php
        $nombreProvincia = "";
        $nombreComuna = "";
        $nombreGiro = "";
        $nombreNombre = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
            if ($nombreProvincia == $row['nombreProvincia']) {
                if ($nombreComuna == $row['nombreComuna']) {
                    if ($nombreGiro == $row['nombreGiro']) {
                        $nombreNombre[] = $row['nombreNombre'];
                    }
                    else { //nombreGiro
                        echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li> ', $nombreNombre).'</li></ul></li></ul>';
                        $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
                        echo '<ul class="clientes_giro"><li>'.$nombreGiro.'<ul class="clientes_nombre">';
                        $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
                    }
                }
                else { // nombreComuna
                    echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li> ', $nombreNombre).'</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>';
                    $nombreComuna = $row['nombreComuna'];
                    echo '<ul class="clientes_comuna"><li>'.$nombreComuna;
                    $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
                    echo '<ul class="clientes_giro"><li>'.$nombreGiro.'<ul class="clientes_nombre">';
                    $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
                }
            }
            else { // nombreProvincia
                if (!empty($nombreNombre)) {
                    echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li> ', $nombreNombre).'</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>';
                }
                $nombreProvincia = $row['nombreProvincia'];
                   // this is the UL i'd like float for every other one.
                echo '<ul class="clientes_provincia"><li>'.$nombreProvincia; 
                $nombreComuna = $row['nombreComuna'];
                echo '<ul class="clientes_comuna"><li>'.$nombreComuna;
                $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
                echo '<ul class="clientes_giro"><li>'.$nombreGiro.'<ul class="clientes_nombre">';
                $nombreNombre = array($row['nombreNombre']);
            }
        }
        echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li> ', $nombreNombre).'</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>';  
?>
```

So what I'd like to do is float every other UL tag of the 'Provincia' echo.
Thanks for the help!

at this moment with what i have i get a list like this:

- Provincia1

  - Comuna1

    - Giro1

      - Nombre1
      - Nombre2

- Provincia2

  - Comuna2

    - Giro2

      - Nombre3
      - Nombre4

I want the provincia 2 be on the right side of provincia 1, and if I have another list
provincia 3 i want it to be under pronvincia 1, and a prinvia 4 beside provincia 3 and so on.., thats what i mean with floating every other UL provincia, hope that helps as an example.

Comment: Posting the actual HTML would probably get a faster solution. Or could do add an example of what you want the HTML to look like?

Comment: @andyb the html is just that the php part, but i want everyother UL tag be floated to the left, so i get a two column list. hope the expample helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultAraucania)) {
    $class = $i++ % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';

    ...

    echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

    ...
}
```

This allows you to easily distinguish between even and odd columns and float "every other" column left.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about IE too much, you can use

```
.clientes_provincia:nth-of-type(odd) { float: left }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your markup and looping is making this problem harder than it should be. I actually think it could just be 1 loop.

The trick here is to use a width on a container `<div>` and each `<ul>` which automatically forces the browser to float two `<ul>`s and then drop to the next row for the following `<ul>`. If you can't use this static width idea then you have 2 very good other solutions already.

Here is a small example which I have tested at http://writecodeonline.com/php/

```
$dataRow = array();
$dataRow[0] = array('nombreProvincia' => 'A123', 'nombreComuna' => 'A456', 'nombreGiro' => 'A789', 'nombreNombre' => array(101, 102));
$dataRow[1] = array('nombreProvincia' => 'B123', 'nombreComuna' => 'B456', 'nombreGiro' => 'B789', 'nombreNombre' => array(201, 202));
$dataRow[2] = array('nombreProvincia' => 'C123', 'nombreComuna' => 'C456', 'nombreGiro' => 'C789', 'nombreNombre' => array(301, 302));

echo '<div style="width:600px">';

foreach ($dataRow as $key => $row) {
        $nombreProvincia = $row['nombreProvincia'];
        $nombreComuna = $row['nombreComuna'];
        $nombreGiro = $row['nombreGiro'];
        $nombreNombre = '<li>'.implode('</li><li>', $row['nombreNombre']).'</li>';

        echo $provincia = <<<HTML
<ul class="clientes_provincia" style="width:200px;float:left;">
    <li>$nombreProvincia
        <ul class="clientes_giro">
            <li>$nombreGiro
                <ul class="clientes_nombre">
                    $nombreNombre
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
HTML;
}

echo '<br style="clear:both"></div>';
```

Also, [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) is awesome if you use PHP >= 4.

Comment: I sincerely hope nobody's using PHP < 4… :)

Comment: thanks but inside Provincia1, can be many comuna1 comuna2 etc.. and inside comuna can be many Giros too

Comment: No problem! I was just trying to show a different way of creating the `<ul>` hierarchy. You could still apply the same principle and extract the data into a similar structure to the one in my example if you wanted to simplify the "view" layer.

Comment: i actually tried but couldn't get it lol, im start using php a couple weeks ago lol, thank you anyways!